# Online meeting invite, access with default name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-live-meeting

Im working with microsoft graph with the new api for teams.

I was wondering if i can set up the access to an online meeting, where i can pass an url to a person with a pre-assigned name on it (like adding a parameter to the url).

If its not a posibility, is any way to do this? and are you planning on adding it? It could be a nice feature to makes things easier when using microsoft teams.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jdc- Could you please share the API's documentation which you are following.

Comment: @Jdc- Are you looking for creating a online meeting using Graph API & get the joinWebUrl to share it with a person so that person can directly join the meeting via clicking on URL?

Otherwise could you please elaborate on your requirement.

Comment: Yes, im using Graph API & get the joinWebUrl to share it. Is there any option to add a name in the query, where i can pass it like: "joinURL?name={name}" ? Or something similar

Comment: Could you please share the Graph API documentation URL which you are referring so that I can check it from my end accordingly.

Comment: No, im still looking for a solution. The parameter on the URL was just an idea to solve the problem (is not in the documentation) But i dont find any way to put a name automatically in an url.

Comment: If it's not mentioned in the documentation so I think it will not work.